# STL priority_queue of pairs<int, struct> error

Tags: c++, struct, priority-queue

Finding a shortest path in a grid and struggling to set up priority queue properly.

```
struct position{
    int row;
    int col;
    position* parent;
    position(int a, int b):row(a),col(b), parent(nullptr){}
};

vector<position>vec;


priority_queue<pair<int, position>, vector<pair<int, position>>, greater<pair<int, position>>>pq;

int distance = 0;
position *t = new p(0,0);

pq.push(make_pair(distance, t));
```

Getting this error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::priority_queue, std::vector >, std::greater > >::push(std::pair)’
     pq.push(make_pair(distance, t));
```

Comment: It's hardly readable, please use typedefs. That will make it easier.

Comment: Your `priority_queue` is of `pair<int, position>`, but you are trying to push in a `pair<int, position*>`

Comment: Please post the real, exact error message produced by your compiler. It looks like you attempted to shorten it for some reason and in doing so left out important information. Copy and paste it instead of trying to retype it.

Comment: I'll start using typedef for a clarity. I was trying to push a pointer to my queue and did not have a proper comparison function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a functor ( or use a lambda) to compare the distance - position pair, `std::greater` won't automatically do it for you. Try this snippet:

```
struct position {
    int row;
    int col;
    position* parent;
    position(int a, int b) :row(a), col(b), parent(nullptr) {}
};

typedef std::pair<int, position> dist_pos_t;

class compare
{
public:
    bool operator()(const dist_pos_t& lhs, const dist_pos_t& rhs)
    {
        return rhs.first < lhs.first;
    }

};
std::priority_queue<dist_pos_t, std::vector<dist_pos_t>, compare >pq;

int main() {
    int distance = 0;
    position *t = new position(0, 0);
    pq.push(std::make_pair(distance, *t));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Declaration of Priority Queue does not match with what you are trying to push.

Declaration should be something like

```
priority_queue<pair<obj1,obj2>pq;
```

`obj1/obj2` can be anything like int or `pair<obj,obj>`

After such declaration you can use

```
pq.push(make_pair(obj1,obj2))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two major issues in your code.

First, your priority_queue is of `std::pair<int, position>`, but you are trying to push in a `std::pair<int, position*>`.

Second, `std::greater<T>` depends on the `>` operator of the underlying type `T`. In your case, it's `std::pair<int, position>`, whose `>` operator depends on the `<` operator of `position` (See [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp)). You need to provide `<` for `position`, or, you can use a custom compare functor type.